# Jquery перекидывает наверх страницы

Tags: jquery, javascript

Доброго времени суток. Странная проблема.

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="name_class">Модальное окно</a>
```

В скрипте уже написал event.preventDefault
$('.modal-form').dialog('open');
И в конце return false;
Однако все равно при нажатии на "модальное окно", он перекдиывает наверх страницы. Проверил скрипты, ничего нет. Что за магия?

upd:
Локализовал проблему. Причина была в самом модальном окне. Там есть <select>. Если его убрать - скакать перестает. Как обычный селект может влиять на это?

upd2: 
Еще ближе к сути подошел. Где-то в бустрапе ошибка. Хотя его с офф сайта брал.

Answer (score 3):

> event.preventDefault**()**

Answer (score 0):

А после

```
void(0)
```

где закрывающие кавычки?

Comment: Я извиняюсь. писал тут.. сейчас скопирую, как у меня в коде
<a class="complaint" href="javascript:void(0);">Пожаловаться</a>

Answer (score 0):

Есть вероятность что поможет `position: fixed;`. Ну а в центр окна и сами отодвинете.

Comment: В плане CSS все нормально. Потому что рядом находится другое модальное окно, которое открывается нормально.
Я их сравнил, после того, как удалил оттуда <select> - стало нормально работать.. Может подскажите, как обычный селект влияет на это?

Comment: Никак не должен влиять. Более точно сказать затрудняюсь.
Надо код смотреть.